# Filesystem for external MicroSD card

Tags: filesystems

Information: Got a new laptop with 32GB eMMC, booted with Lubuntu. Got a 64GB MicroSD card.

Problem: The microSD card needs a FS that is as fast as possible as it is technically a "native drive".

Question: I need a filesystem that is optimised for MicroSD cards, native to Linux systems (or by FUSE compatibility).

Additional info: I am thinking between ext4, exFAT, but is there a better optimised FS that you would know for microSD cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f2fs seems designed for this case. See https://lwn.net/Articles/518988/ from where I'm quoting:

"f2fs [...] is the "flash-friendly file system", a new filesystem for Linux recently [2012] announced by engineers from Samsung. Unlike jffs2 and logfs, f2fs is not targeted at raw flash devices, but rather at the specific hardware that is commonly available to consumers — SSDs, eMMC, SD cards, and other flash storage with an FTL (flash translation layer) already built in."

Comment: Thanks! But for future references, on Lubuntu I had to install f2fs-tools and libf2fs0 to be able to format it in f2fs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use BTRFS if I had to specify something. It has some awareness of flash sensibilities.

UFS 3.0 would be the successor to exFAT which one can only hope Microsoft supports on Win11 some day; it seems to work, but files disappear to seamlessly occupied blocks with no files, on remount.

There's an UBFS that's an unfiltered block filesystem; not what I mean. I mean the U as on the card UFS logo U. Toshiba announced the standard a ways back.

And yet, my handy tools for determining if a card are corrupted are broken down by card maker (standard implementation, as it were...) No common log to see AFAICT.

Comment: I thought about it, and my conclusion is that if the drive is mission critical (as it is in the question), then you'd probably want something that is a bit more corruption-resistant, such as NTFS, or ext3/4.